# Could STM32 Discovery boards debug STM8 chip?

Tags: stm32, debugging, swd, stm8

I know that STM32 discovery boards could debug another STM32 chip. But could it debug STM8 chip too? Is STM8's debugging interface compatible with SWD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. STM8 parts use SWIM, not SWD.

The *standalone* [ST-Link v2](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html) supports SWIM, but the embedded ones on Discovery and Nucleo boards do not.